# Adding multiple lines to arrayList

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm making a simple app that will display text typed in editText to listView. So i made arrayList and set adapter for listView to get text from there but right now i'm having this problem where my listView is showing only one line. And when i want to add text to another line it only text of the first.

```
fun addToList(view: View){
        findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        var list = ArrayList<String>()
        list.add(editText.text.toString())

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list)
        toDoList.adapter = adapter

    }
```

Comment: http://androidrocksonmobility.blogspot.com/2011/09/show-multiline-text-inside-spinner.html

Answer (score 1):

The text of an EditText is a single string, so what you need is to split this string to lines using `String.lines()`

Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/lines.html

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are creating your new ArrayList every time you are calling your function. You need to initialize your ArrayList inside `onCreate()`

```
var list = ArrayList<String>()
```